# How can I remove scroll bar in the bottom side of my division?

Tags: html, css

I want to set ,tex1,tex2 and text3 division,in the Text Division class,without Scroll bar in the bottom side on it.but as you see there is a scroll bar in the bottom side .what is my mistake that does not let me ,not to have scroll bar in the bottom side of Text Class Div?
[image]
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        direction: rtl;
    }

```
.Text {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 50px 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.Text1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border: 1px dashed green;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.Text2 {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    text-align: center;
}

.Text3 {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 80px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.Resume {
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #00d363;
    border: 1px solid #00d363;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    text-align: center;
}

.RezumeA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.RezumeA:hover {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #00d363;
    border: #00d363;
}
```

```html
<body>



            <div class="Text">
                <div class="Text1">بیش از 5000 شغل</div>
                <div class="Text2">شغل رویایی ات دست پیدا کن</div>
                <div class="Text3">ما بهترین و سریعترین ،راههای دستیابی به شغل مورد علاقه تان فراهم کرده ایم</div>
                <div class="Resume"><a href="#" class="RezumeA">ارسال رزومه</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the attribute of `overflow` in `Text` class of your CSS to `hidden`:

```
.Text {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Basically, since your overflow was set to `auto`, it tried to scale the content for which it had to show the scrollbar. For more details check out this W3schools documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can disable scrollbars with `overflow: hidden;` It can be overflow in general, but if you want only horizontal to be hidden, you can put `overflow-x: hidden`, and for vertical: `overflow-y: hidden`
So, in your css you can put it like this:

```
.Resume {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #00d363;
    border: 1px solid #00d363;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do

```
.Text > div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

so all nested divs with border fits into the parent el